# unresolved symbol specialization of templatized method

Tags: c++, templates, unresolved-external

This code is not able to resolve `void K::func<B>(B&)`.

```
struct K {
  template <typename T> void func(T &t);
};

struct B {
  void ok();
};

// definition
template <typename T> void K::func(T &t) { t->ok(); }

// getting: undefined reference to `void K::func<B>(B&)'
// nm says '                 U void K::func<B>(B&)'
template <> void K::func<B>(B &b);
template <> void K::func(B &b);

int main() {
  K k;
  B b;
  k.func(b);
};
```

Note: Several other questions at SO were related to compilation; I
m stuck at linking . Please point me to duplicate if any.

UPDATE:
I'm following http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization , look for functions g1 or g2 ;

UPDATE2: fixed 'func' to 'K::func' to fix 'out of class member template definition', still K::func can't be specialized.

Comment: You haven't defined `K::func` anywhere.

Comment: For that matter, there is no `B::ok` defined anywhere either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `template <> void K::func(B &b);` is only a declaration, for definition `template void K::func(B &b);` is needed. The updated code:

```
struct K {
  template <typename T> void func(T &t);
};

struct B {
  void ok();
};

// definition
template <typename T> void K::func(T &t) { t.ok(); }
// specialiation: Do NOT put template <> here !!!    
template void K::func(B &b);

int main() {
  K k;
  B b;
  k.func(b);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide definition like this:

```
template <> void K::func<B>(B &b) {}
```

Also the following two are equivalent only in the second case T is deduced from the parameter type:

```
template <> void K::func<B>(B &b);
template <> void K::func(B &b);
```

Comment: I've `template <typename T> void func(T &t) { t->ok(); }` .. the question is how to  specialize it for T = B ! , not to redefine func for T = B

Comment: @vrdhn but this template is not related to `struct K`. For struct K you can write `template<> void K::func(B &b) { b.ok(); }`.

Comment: oh yeah .. Thanks, i guess I needed another paid eyes (-:
But stil, this defination needs to be templatized for my use case.

Comment: But for several class B,C,D..., I'll need to reimplment it.